# Linking files with Filezilla - not working

Tags: magento-1.9, pdf, file-upload, ftp, download-link

I have copied and pasted a working link and adjusted it to match the PDF I currently have in Filezilla. But I cannot get it to work... the code I have is:

href="/media/brochure/work_shelter_flyer_general.pdf" target="_blank">

Work and Storage Shelter

the file is in the correct folder in Filezilla so I'm wondering - what have I missed?!

Comment: For some reason it wouldn't let me add the whole code...

Answer (score 0):

Try to download your pdf with direct link http://YOURDOMAIN.com/media/brochure/work_shelter_flyer_general.pdf in browser.

If it works you can use full url with http://... for href value. If not check another files in media folder and double check spelling.